# aws cognito rbac like permission handling

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

The problem I am facing is to give the authenticated “user” a role-based-access-control like behaviour to have e.g. two different types of authenticated users with different permissions on resources. But it seems to be that I just can have an authenticated user and not a more detailed gradation this. The following to illustrate it:

```
-authenticated user
--user
--- access to: ECS Group A
--Author
--- access to: ECS Group A
--- access to: ECS Group B

-unauthenticated user
```

When I would build the authentication with lambda functions I could add a "authenticate function" in front of each lambda function. But this seems odd. I am looking for a better approach to deal with cognito's access mechanism to differentiate between users on a higher level than the resource itself.

Comment: How did you ultimately solve this? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on where you know which type of user a user is, but if you initialize the Cognito identity client a certain way, you can tell it which auth role you want to assume.

If you were using Android, it'd look like this:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getContext(), // get the context for the current activity        
    "1234567890", // your AWS Account id     
    "us-east-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX", // your identity pool id    
    "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/YourRoleName",// an authenticated role ARN
    "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/YourRoleName", // an unauthenticated role ARN
    Regions.US_EAST_1 //Region
);
```

Comment: I want to know who the user is when he logs in also for HATEOAS behaviors. But as in your example I just can play with authenticated or unauthenticated like it is shown in the comments?

Comment: That is correct. As of now, the above example is the only way to use multiple auth/unauth roles with Cognito.

Comment: If you were using Android, meaning the client? Meaning implement RBAC by letting the client pick a role?